# Cupy Code Optimization: How to speed up nested for loops

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, cupy, numpy-einsum

I would like to optimize the python code between the 2 `perf_counter` functions.
By using `cupy` I already obtained substantial improvement compared to `numpy`.
I was asking myself if there is some reordering or vectorization that I am missing.
The main constraint is that I should not be building any tensor(ndarray) that is bigger than dim^4, since this is part of some memory optimization of a bigger project, for which a method that scales with dim^5 is already known and better performing.

```py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp
from time import perf_counter
dim = 60
T_final = cp.random.rand(dim,dim,dim,dim)
T_start = cp.random.rand(dim,dim,dim,dim)
U = cp.random.rand(dim,dim,dim)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
start = perf_counter()
for xf in range(0,dim):
    for yu in range(0,dim):
        B = cp.einsum("ij,kim->kmj",U[:,:,yu],T_start[xf,:,:,:])
        for xb in range(0,dim):
            C = cp.einsum("kmj,kjs->ms",B,T_start[:,xb,:,:])
            T_final[xf,xb,yu,:]=cp.einsum("msc,ms",U,C)
cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
print(perf_counter()-start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `cupy` well, but I don't think this matters a lot, for the sake of simplicty I'll show how to simplify these nested `einsum` calls with `numpy`. So first it is a good idea to wrap everything into one `einsum` call and then do the optimization after.

My recommendation would be working from the inner most loop outwards, and removing loops and adding the corresponding indices to `einsum`.

So to eliminate the loop over `xb`, we can just use the corresponding array dimension instead, so from the original

```
for xf in range(0,dim):
    for yu in range(0, dim):
        B = cp.einsum("ij,kim->kmj", U[:, :, yu], T_start[xf, :, :, :])
        for xb in range(0, dim):
            C = cp.einsum("kmj,kjs->ms", B, T_start[:, xb, :, :])
            T_final2[xf, xb, yu, :] = cp.einsum("msc,ms->c", U, C) #adding the -> c to be explicit
```

we get

```
for xf in tqdm.tqdm(range(0,dim)):
    for yu in range(0, dim):
        B = cp.einsum("ij,kim->kmj", U[:, :, yu], T_start[xf, :, :, :])
        C = cp.einsum("kmj,kbjs->bms", B, T_start)
        T_final[xf, :, yu, :] = cp.einsum("msc,bms->bs", U, C)
```

Now we can also remove the outer loops in the same way:

```
B = cp.einsum("iju,fkim->ufkmj", U, T_start)
C = cp.einsum("ufkmj,kbjs->ufbms", B, T_start)
T_final2 = cp.einsum("msc,ufbms->fbuc", U, C)
```

But we are not done yet. Instead of doing multiple calls to `einsum`, we can also wrap everything in one call, to profit more from the non-python code in numpy/cp, as `einsum` supports multiple arguments.
We can just plug in the corresponding entries, and add the indices. You may experience a slowdown though,
as the evaluation order might not be ideal. So first we get

```
C = cp.einsum("iju,fkim,kbjs->ufbms", U, T_start, T_start)
T_final2 = cp.einsum("msc,ufbms->fbuc", U, C)
```

and after eliminating the second call we get the following in the same way

```
T_final2 = cp.einsum("msc,iju,fkim,kbjs->fbuc", U, U, T_start, T_start)
```

While there is `np.einsum_path`, there is a much more sophisticated library
called `opt_einsum`, which does exactly what you want. So you can replace the call above with

```
from opt_einsum import contract 
T_final2 = contract("msc,iju,fkim,kbjs->fbuc", U, U, T_start, T_start)
```

Note that this does work with `cupy` too, as it supports [various backends](https://optimized-einsum.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends.html)!
If you want to explicitly what kind of contraction path is being used, you can use `oe.contract_path()`.

To verify how they behave, we can do some measurmenets (code below), and indeed, the original implementation is `O(dim^5)` while the optimized one is `O(dim^4)`:

[image: timing diagram]

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
cp = np
from time import perf_counter
import opt_einsum as oe
def eval_dim(dim):
    print(f'printing {dim}')
    T_final = cp.random.rand(dim, dim, dim, dim)
    T_start = cp.random.rand(dim, dim, dim, dim)
    U = cp.random.rand(dim, dim, dim)
    start = perf_counter()
    for xf in range(0,dim):
        for yu in range(0, dim):
            B = cp.einsum("ij,kim->kmj", U[:, :, yu], T_start[xf, :, :, :])
            for xb in range(0, dim):
                C = cp.einsum("kmj,kjs->ms", B, T_start[:, xb, :, :])
                T_final[xf, xb, yu, :] = cp.einsum("msc,ms->c", U, C)
    print(time_orig := perf_counter()-start)
    start = perf_counter()
    T_final2 = oe.contract("msc,iju,fkim,kbjs->fbuc", U, U, T_start, T_start)
    print(np.allclose(T_final, T_final2))  # should all be small numbers
    print(time_oe := perf_counter()-start)
    return (time_orig, time_oe)

def main():
    dims = np.arange(4, 25)
    times = np.array([eval_dim(dim) for dim in dims])
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.loglog(dims, times[:, 0], 'o-')
    plt.loglog(dims, times[:, 1], 'o-')
    plt.loglog(dims, 3e-7*dims**4, ':')
    plt.loglog(dims, 3e-7*dims**5, ':')
    plt.xlabel('dims'); plt.ylabel('time')
    plt.legend(['orig', 'opt_einsum', 'n^4', 'n^5'])
    plt.show()

main()
```